# Facebook Graph /me missing email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We have issues with our web app and Facebook.

I'm doing the Login with scope `email`

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    // my code
}, {scope: 'email', auth_type: 'rerequest', return_scopes: true});
```

I got the popup asking permission for the email, and other fields
[image]

I accept it, but then after getting the access_token, I call

`https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email,picture.type(large)&access_token={MY_TOKEN}`

The email field is not in the response

[image]

What I don't understand is that user is a test user created on Facebook app page. One in Two users I create have this issue. For some other users, I have the email with the same exact procedure

[image]

Do you know what could happen?

Comment: Not all users has a verified email address.

Comment: @WizKid They are tested users, automaticly created in my application dashboard. I see no difference between then when I connect into them

Answer (score 2):

We are experiencing the same issue.

WizKid is right. Try using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and you'll see that when you get no email, this tool shows "The email field was not returned. This may be because the email was missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed." message.

Comment: Thank you for this tool, I didn't knew it. Yes I also noticed that email wasn't confirmed, but nothing appear in the user account regarding that. My main issue was that Facebook team refused to enable my app because I refuse users without emails. And they are so stupid that they never understood that some of their users didn't have confirmed emails. So I just gave them fake emails in my app until they accept to validate my app...

Comment: It's incredible how stupid they make this. I have the exact same problem right now. Thanks for telling me how to get past this unnecessary convoluted circus.